# OrientDB REST API available on same web-app as embedded server (using a relative path)

Tags: orientdb

I'm writing a web-app for distribution, with an embedded OrientDB, and was wondering if you could give me some clues on how to also bundle OrientDB Studio, without having to use the built-in web server. (the reason for this is that a lot of hosting providers don't allow to use other ports so wouldn't be able to make studio available just by deploying the app)
The idea is to make OrientDB's REST API available from a relative path in my web-app, so that studio can communicate with it, but I have no clue on where to start looking. First I need to know if it is even possible to make the REST protocol available if not using the provided listeners on the built-in web server, then if it would be possible to point studio operations to a relative address.

This seems like a problem that probably someone else has came across, so if not with OrientDB, maybe experience with a similar problem using other embeddable DBs might help me...

Answer (score 0):

you could create a reverse proxy in Apache to bind the port 80 under the address "/orientdb" for example to -> localhost:2480.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lvca. But that wouldn't be just deploying an app though. This needs to be distributed and can't assume the users will be able to make changes to Apache configuration. I was thinking something more in the lines of exposing my own REST service that will just delegate to the methods in your REST service internally. But not sure how that will that will play out with security and such. Does it seem like a good way to go to you anyway?

Comment: It works very well if you use the OrientDB users. In this way you can limit access to records per user basis. Look at horizontal or record-level security: https://github.com/nuvolabase/orientdb/wiki/Security

Comment: @Lvca could you possibly expand this answer? I would like to access the OrientDB REST API through the web (not through localhost). Would a reverse proxy accomplish this?